# Using custom component for data in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

So I have a custom component that looks something like this:

**student.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'student',
  templateUrl: 'student.html'
})
export class StudentComponent {

  @Input() name: string;
  public status: string;
  public notes: string;

  public tardyTime: string;
  public isTardy : boolean = false;;

  constructor() {
  }

  tardyClicked(){
    this.isTardy = true;
  }

  notTardy(){
    this.isTardy = false;
  }
}
```

and the template looks like this:

**student.html**

```
<h4 class="padding">{{name}}</h4>
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="status">
    <ion-segment-button value="p" (ionSelect)="notTardy()">
      Present
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="t" (ionSelect)="tardyClicked()" >
      Tardy
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="a" (ionSelect)="notTardy()">
      Absent
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
  <ion-item *ngIf="isTardy" >
    <ion-label>Tardy Time:</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="h:mm a" [(ngModel)]="tardyTime"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]= "notes" type="text" placeholder="Notes:"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

Now I use this custom component in my app like so:

**page.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <student *ngFor="let student of studentArray" [name]="student" ></student>
  </ion-list>
  <p>
    <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="showPrompt()" block>Submit</button>
  </p>
</ion-content>
```

I want to be able to create an array of objects within my page.ts which will pull from the student components and create an object for each which would be

```
{
  name : studentcomponent.name
  status : studentcomponent.status
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do it create the object array in your `page.ts` with an initial status value.
Then pass the student object to the student component like this:

```
<ion-list>
    <student *ngFor="let student of studentArray"
       [student]="student"></student>
</ion-list>
```

The student component will change the status, and it will change in your `page.ts` as well.

Comment: I tried this, however it seems the values aren't binding both ways. It sets the student components initial values, however when i change these values it does not send the changed data back to the object within page.ts

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work, but if you pass the student object as input - it does see this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/hrzWGF7fSTCvKY2BfmeL?p=preview